# .htaccess to serve static files; route all other requests to index.php in same folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm looking to make an .htaccess file that serves all static images as normal, but routes any other requests to the index.php file that's in the *same folder* as said .htaccess file. This is my code so far, which doesn't seem to work. It defers to an index.php that's higher up in the folder structure.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php
RewriteRule ^index.php/?(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Comment: If this is at a sub-folder level, try removing the `RewriteBase` directive, as that's what's telling the server to use the higher up part.  Alternatively, change the `RewriteBase` to be the folder you are in.  That should work

Comment: Thanks. I decided to do the latter. When I use `RewriteBase /PATH-TO-PROJECT/`, it works. You might add this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is at sub-folder level, the issue is that the `RewriteBase` is pointing at the root directory.  You can either remove the `RewriteBase` directive, or change it to be the folder that the .htaccess file is in so the rewriting can work from that point.

Comment: Thanks. `RewriteBase /PATH-TO-PROJECT/` is a perfect solution.